# Javascript Regex to match multiple currencies symbol and amount

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match  different currencies like €, £, ¥ etc.

I have follow in Regex to detect only dollars but want it to detect any currency symbol:

`/\$[\s]?([\d\.\,]+)[\s]*([\w]*)/g`

Comment: You have to provide test cases

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883580/regular-expression-that-supports-multiple-currency-formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all the symbols you want to match into a character set at the beginning:

```
[$€£¥]\s?([\d.,]+)\s*(\w*)
```

Also, a character set with only one token in it is superfluous, and you almost never need to escape characters in a character set (except, of course, with a metacharacter like `\d`).

Comment: You don't have to escape the dot and comma in the character class.